# Subgroup of a group with 24 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group of order $24$, which has four $3$-sylow subgroups.  We know that may contain  $1$ or $3$ 2-sylow subgroup.  How can I prove that there only exists one $2$-sylow subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What is the size of each 2-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: The size is $8$, but I don´t know how do the counts, maybe is something easy that iTdon´t see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your claim is true.
For example take $S_4$.It has four 3-sylow subgroup  and three 2-sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. $S_4$ is a counterexample.